# Prove that the continuous $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ has a global max and min

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, transformation

I am having this continuous transformation
$f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$  and $\ f\ (\mathbb C)$ is bounded
Now I have to prove that there are a global maximum and a global minimum.

---

My thoughts:
I think there is a global maximum and a global minimum, because of this theorem:

[image]

---

Questions: Can I use this for my proof? (I am not sure about the "compactness")

Comment: What about $f(z) = \frac{1}{1 + |z|}$, for example?

Comment: But $\mathbb C$ is not compact, so that theorem does not apply.